# What could be causing a QSslError::CertificateSignatureFailed on Symbian?

Tags: qt, symbian, dropbox-api

I have a [Qt Symbian Dropbox app](http://coinonedge.com/droper) which was working normally, but recently many users have been reporting an SSL handshake failure when performing any action which requires an API call (all API calls to Dropbox servers are supposed to be done using HTTPS).

When investigating the error, I noticed that the `QNetworkReply` emits an `sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)` signal which parameter includes `QSslError` objects with `QSslError::CertificateSignatureFailed` set as their error.

What could be causing this? Could it be related to the heartbleed bug? Is it maybe that the Dropbox servers have been updated in a way that stops whichever OpenSSL version installed on users' devices to work with them?

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Do you know what SSL signature methods your platform supports? Did the errors start immediately after heartbleed? (The certificates were indeed changed then.)

Comment: How do I know what signature methods the platform supports? And yes, the error started immediately after heartbleed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symbian/Qt, so I can't say how you would look into this on that platform, but there's some more information here on the Dropbox side for context: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=114800